# How can I use dismissableMask in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am trying to hide a dialog when I click outside of dialog, but I can't make it with dismissabeMask in PrimeNG. Can anyone help me please ?

**HTML**

```
<button type="text" (click)="showDialog()" pButton icon="fa-external-link-square" label="Show"></button>
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [(dismissableMask)]="mask"> 
    <p-header>
        Error Message
    </p-header>
        <label>Label</label>
    <p-footer>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog
```

**TS**

```
mask: boolean = false;
showDialog() {
  this.msg = this.errorMessages[id];
  this.display = true;
  this.mask = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [(dismissableMask)]="mask">
```

with

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" modal="true" dismissableMask="true">
```

---

If you don't add `modal="true"`, it won't work (see [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ONZaFPUUDcBnUlxkW52?p=preview))

Comment: it is working but , background is scrolling when i try to scroll.

Comment: Add `[blockScroll]=true` to your `p-dialog`.